# NSScrollView will not scroll on NSAlert as Accessory?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to use an NSScrollView as an accessory on an NSAlert?

I want to prompt the user, and display a list of images to them as part of the prompt.

My thought was to display an NSScrollView that contains the images, but when the scrollview appears as part of the NSAlert sheet, it appears, as does it's contents, but you can't scroll it.

I'm not clear on whether I am missing some simple step on the NSScrollView setup, or if this is simply a constraint on NSAlert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code in question:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:prompt
                                 defaultButton:defaultButtonText
                               alternateButton:altButtonText
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@",infoText];

// create the scrollview
NSScrollView* scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 250, imageHeight)];

// fill the scrollview with images
int i = 0;
for (NSImage* image in images)
{
    // create a new image view
    NSImageView*  imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(i*150, 5, 145, 145)];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    // add the subview to the content view and increase size of contents
    [scrollview.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollview.contentView setFrame: NSMakeRect(0,0,(i+1)*150, 155) ];

    // increment image counter
    i++;
}

// add the scrollview to the alert sheet
[alert setAccessoryView:scrollview];

// show the alert sheet
NSWindow* win = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:win
                  modalDelegate:delegate
                 didEndSelector:endselector
                    contextInfo:nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to add the image views to the scroll view's document view, not its content view.

Comment: Eureka, you are correct.  The images wouldn't show up when I added them to the documentView, so I added them to contentView.  But the reason they wouldn't show is because I never set the document view, and was calling addSubview on Nil.  I just created an empty NSView, called setDocumentView, and changed the addSubview to use documentView.  All good.  Many Thanks.